# JAR Executável muito mais lento que a execução pelo Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, jar

Bom dia,

Eu tenho um projeto no netbeans que utiliza o maven para construir um jar executável, até ai tudo bem.
O problema é que quando eu executo o projeto pelo ".jar" que é gerado pelo maven, a execução demora muito mais tempo para executar determinadas funções do que  quando eu executo pela IDE do netbeans. Pra ter uma ideia, o início do programa executado pelo Netbeans demora 8 segundos, enquanto que no ".jar" demora aproximadamente uns 25 segundos. Nesse início eu faço a leitura de alguns arquivos de configuração, e de certificados digitais.  Outras funções que demoram mais tempo, como a assinatura de documentos xml, que já demoravam um pouco no IDE, duram uma eternidade no ."jar". Além disso, o estranho é que meu  projeto tem poucas bibliotecas.

Também procurei em outros tópicos, encontrei muitos dizendo (como esse [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685103/runnable-jar-runs-too-slow-compared-to-eclipse-project)) pra gerar o ".jar" com a opção de extrair as bibliotecas no arquivo gerado, mas eu não sei de fato como faz isso no maven. Eu até tentei de algumas formas, mas não sei se eu estou errando ao fazer, ou se não surtiu nenhum efeito.

Vou postar aqui meu arquivo pom.xml pra ver se alguém tem alguma ideia do que eu posso fazer pra resolver isso.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.argus</groupId>
    <artifactId>CronosAuxiliar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>br.com.samuelweb</groupId>  
            <artifactId>java-nfe</artifactId>  
            <version>3.10.8</version>  
        </dependency>  

        <!--Dependência de Log-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.argus</groupId>
            <artifactId>CronosLibNotaFiscal</artifactId>
            <version>[1,)</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>  
            <name>Repositorio Autocom SnapShot</name>  
            <id>Snapshot</id>  
            <url>http://www.autocomsistemas.com.br:8081/nexus/content/repositories/autocom/</url>  
        </repository> 
    </repositories>    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>br.com.argus.cronos.main.CronosAuxiliar</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>  
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>    
</project>
```

Comment: Só para eliminar algumas possibilidades. A JVM que você está usando para rodar o Jar é a mesma do que a do Netbeans? Você está passando as mesmas configurações de memória, etc para a JVM do que o Netbeans (de uma olhada em [`netbeans.conf`](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf))). Pode ser que o uber Jar seja realmente o garga-lo, mas eu com certeza verificaria o ambiente.

Comment: Eu olhei nesse arquivo, descobri qual é a versão que o netbeans usa, mas não sei qual o meu windows tá usando pra rodar na linha de comando :( Os comandos que são executados são os que estão na linha "netbeans_default_options"? Porque se for isso, tentei executar aqui com elas e deu erro no java. Apareceu que a maquina virtual parou de funcionar.

Comment: Oi Lucas, você pode usar o comando `java -version` para descobrir a versão da JVM e o comando `for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i` no CMD do Windows para descobrir o caminho. As *switches* são essas mesmas e o fato de ter dado erro é interessantes. Vale a pena experimentar ao menos com as de memória, e.g. `java -Xms1G -Xmx5G -jar MinhaAplicacao.jar`.

Comment: No windows eu to usando a versão do jre "1.8.0_144-b01" e no netbeans é a versão  do jdk "1.8.0_05", de fato a aplicação tá rodando em máquinas virtuais diferentes né? As opções que eu consegui colocar na linha de comando foram essas "-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m". As outras eu fui colocando de uma em uma e foi dando erro em todas.